# Stage not drawing it's Actors

Tags: java, libgdx

So I have this world called pokemon world and  this is how I atempt to render my stage which contains a custom actor called MenuActor

```
public PokemonWorld(ChromeGame game) {
    this.game = game;
    createMenu();
}

protected void createMenu() {
    stage = new Stage();
    stage.setViewport(150, 720, true);
    menu = new MenuActor();
    stage.addActor(menu);
    Gdx.app.log(ChromeGame.LOG, "Menu Created");

}
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);

    if (menuVisible) {
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

}
```

And this is my custom Actor

```
public class MenuActor extends Actor {

    Texture region;

    public MenuActor() {
        super();
        region = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("imgs/OptionBox.png"));
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch, float parentAlpha) {
        super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
        batch.draw(region, getX(), getY(), 150, 720, 0, 0,
                region.getWidth(), getHeight());
    }

}
```

As you can see, the actor is given a texture and in its draw method, it draws it. In the PokemonWorld class it adds the MenuActor to the stageand the asks the stage to draw by `stage.draw();`

What am I missing? I feel like I'm doing all the right steps but I might be missing a step/line of code.

Comment: What is happening? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Kon It supposed to draw a box on the screen, see the MenuActor, I set the actor to have the optionbox.png as a texture

Comment: Is `menuVisible` true?

Comment: @DanielGabriel: yes it is, later on I'll be changing it true/false depending on the key pressed but at the moment it is set to true

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Add a log/print statement to your draw method.  Its probably being called, but your draw method is broken.  (`*region.*getHeight()` maybe?)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the last parameter should be some **height** (instead of `getWidth()`).

```
batch.draw(region, getX(), getY(), 150, 720, 0, 0,
                region.getWidth(), getWidth());
```

Comment: Sorry thats a typo, I fixed it, it however still doesn't work